# electron-vue: store properties set but not rendering (VUEX)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, vuex

Folks,

I am starting electron-vuejs desktop application programming. I am learning how `vuex` works through an self-taught example. Here is my issue:

I have a component, whose template is,

```
<template>                                                                       
<div id="wrapper">                                                             
 <main>                                                                       
  <div class="left-side">                                                    
    <span class="title">                                                     
      <h2>{{ titleName }}</h2>                                               
    </span>                                                                                                             
  </div>                                                                                                                                                 
 </main>
```

corresponding script section is as follows,

```
<script>                                                                        
import { mapState } from 'vuex'                                                 

export default {                                                                
  name: 'game-page',                                                                                                                         
  computed: mapState([ 'titleName' ]) // map this.title to store.state.title    
}  
</script>
```

I have defined the `titleName` property in my `store.js` which resides as `./store/modules/store.js` and the contents of the same:

```
cont state = {
  titleName: 'Welcome to planet earth'
}

export default {
  state
}
```

Everything works fine: in the sense that I am not getting any error/warning message in the `vue-devtools` console. I could see the `vuex` states as defined in the `store.js` in the console. However, I am not getting the title rendered in the component.

My understanding is `mapState` fetches the property  from the store and binds to the variable in the component. With that understanding, I didn't define a `gettr`, But, it seem that it is not happening.

I must be doing something silly or missing something obvious. Could someone shed some light on how to troubleshoot/fix this issue? `Vue-2.5.17` is what I am using.

**EDIT:**
This is what my `index.js` is,

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import state from './modules/store.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    state
  },
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production'
})
```

My directory structure is,

```
src
├── index.ejs
├── main
│   ├── index.dev.js
│   └── index.js
└── renderer
    ├── App.vue
    ├── assets
    │   └── logo.png
    ├── components
    │   ├── StonePaperScissors
    │   │   └── GameStates.vue
    │   └── StonePaperScissors.vue
    ├── main.js
    ├── router
    │   └── index.js
    └── store
        ├── index.js
        ├── modules
            ├── index.js
            └── store.js
```

Comment: does your store wiht `titleName` load as module?

Comment: I have added, how am I loading the store in my question. I am a beginner. I am not quite understood your question with proper context.

Comment: Yes, After surfing through and reading on the net, it loads as a module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I think you should name your module something different from `state` to avoid confusing in future :) . I will use name 'your_module_name' below.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import state from './modules/store.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    your_module_name: state
  },
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production'
})
```

If you load your "sub-store" as module but **not namespaced** you can fix issue using another `mapState` signature:

```
computed: mapState({ titleName: state => state.your_module_name.titleName })
```

Or you can make module **namespaced** and use this:

```
computed: mapState('your_module_name', ['titleName'])
```

Yes, `mapState` behavior for non-namespaced modules is not obvious.

Comment: Thanks @MaxSinev. I am not able to get that with your suggestion. Probably, still making something wrong. I am not able to understand what this line say `({ titleName: state => state.your_module_name.titleName })`. I am assuming this as reassigning the state property to another. In that what does `state` stands for? (Now I realize I should use different naming). Thanks once again.

Comment: @RussellB this line says "map store property of `your_module_name` state to Vue component computed property", so you can use it like `this.titleName` and will change if store property changed. `state` is just function param, it's just state of your store. By the way you can map store property by yourself without `mapState`, just define computed property: `titleName() { return this.$store.state.your_module_name.titleName }`

Comment: Thanks @MaxSinev. Your suggestion of defining the computed property withour `mapState` worked. However, I am curious why doesn't the `mapState` helper function work for me. I have tried `namespaced: true` under `export default` in the store definition file. That is not working too (following your advise of namespacing). Is is this something to do with version of Vuejs? I am using 2.5.17.

Comment: @RussellB, this is not Vue version issue, I can provide jsfiddle with namespaced and non-namespaced mapState usage, check https://jsfiddle.net/maxsinev/mLude4kg/ Hope it will help :)

Comment: I appreciate your kindness. I have finally managed, after adding `namespaced: true` under the modules export, from your jsfiddle example. Now things are working and moreover, I understood the concept of exporting store modules and namespace.